# Using a macro, how do you script to delete 2 columns (T & U) based on Column "N" value?

Tags: vba, excel

I need assistance using VBA to program a macro to delete all the values in columns "T & U" based on column "N" that are equal to "Closed".

So to simplify this: If Column "N" = Closed, Columns "T" and "U" should have no value.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  If you're not sure where to start try looking up `Range.ClearContents` using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Clearer()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim r1 As Long

    Set w = Sheet1 'Set this to the (name) of the sheet.
    Set r = w.UsedRange

    r1 = r.Row

    For i = r1 To r1 + r.Rows.Count - 1
        If w.Cells(i, 14) = "Closed" Then w.Range(w.Cells(i, 20), w.Cells(i,  21)).ClearContents
    Next i

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```